# Databinding behaving differently on textbox and label

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, c#-4.0

I have a database with a row that has "TEXTTEXT" inside a "noteText" column and `null` in that column for a different row.  If I run a query that generates 1 rows, then run a different query that has 2 rows, `Eval("noteText")` returns different information when placed in a `TextBox` vs. placed in a `Label`. The `TextBox` and `Label` were created specifically for this test; it is not referenced in the codebehind.  I think the `TextBox` for row 1 of the second query is somewhow pulling the data used in row1 of the first query.

I don't think it could be a browser-related issue since the source code of the returned page is itself incorrect.

Aspx file code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Notes" SortExpression="noteid">
    <ItemTemplate>
        STARTXX
        <asp:TextBox ID="AtxtNote" ViewStateMode="Disabled" runat="server"
            TextMode= "SingleLine" Width="260" Text='<%# Eval("noteText")  %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="BtxtNote" runat="server" Width="260"
            Text='<%# Eval("noteText") %>' />
        <br />
        ENDXX
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

---

Source code on page:

```
STARTXX
    <input name="ctl00$CPH1$gv$ctl02$AtxtNote" type="text"
            value="TEXTTEXT" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gv_ctl02_AtxtNote" 
            style="width:260px;" />
            <br />
    <span id="ctl00_CPH1_gv_ctl02_BtxtNote"
            style="display:inline-block;width:260px;"></span><br />
ENDXX
```

---

Actual spacing is a bit different; I edited the text of the source and output code to prevent horizontal scrolling.

I expected both `Eval` calls to show an empty string.

Comment: Interesting :) More than happy if you catch this issue and share with us.

Comment: Secondly, can you remove ViewStateMode="Disabled" this property and check, whether the result will be same ?

Comment: @Muhammad: Removing `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` does not change the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed it by adding more calls to `DataBind`.

The current theory is that the `TextBox` was being submitted when clicking the button to query the database.  After the `DataBind` happened, Asp.Net repopulated the `TextBox` with the data that was submitted.  The `TextBox` now logically corresponded to a different row in the database, but was in the same position as the `TextBox` from the previous page view and thus had the same `ClientID`.

One reason for this suspicion is that the posts were triggering `OnTextChanged` events.

I'm still unhappy with this; I don't have full confidence that I know what's going on, even though it is now working.